# Select id by newest date, group by id

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Database is MySQL 5.7

Table:

| ID | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kl010622 | 2023-05-15 13:46:05 | 2 |
| kl010622 | 2023-10-05 14:30:49 | 1 |
| kl010622 | 2023-07-05 14:30:49 | 4 |
| kl011111 | 2023-07-05 11:30:49 | 0 |
| kl011111 | 2023-07-05 14:30:49 | 3 |

Query:

```
SELECT
    x.ID AS `ID`,
    x.data,
    x.type
FROM
    (SELECT
         sitemanager.b_crm_deal.TITLE AS `ID`,
         TIMESTAMP(`b_crm_act`.`CREATED`) AS `data`,
         `b_crm_act`.`RESULT_STREAM` AS `type`
     FROM
         sitemanager.b_crm_act 
     LEFT JOIN 
         sitemanager.b_crm_deal ON sitemanager.b_crm_act.OWNER_ID = sitemanager.b_crm_deal.ID
     WHERE 
         PROVIDER_TYPE_ID = 'CALL' 
         AND sitemanager.b_crm_deal.CATEGORY_ID = "31") AS x
```

As a result, I want to receive a table grouped by ID with latest date and corresponding type

| ID | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kl010622 | 2023-10-05 14:30:49 | 1 |
| kl011111 | 2023-07-05 14:30:49 | 3 |